# oauth scopes google classroom API

Tags: google-classroom

I am trying to get round a problem with my code which states

"403 when requesting https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/582805726/students?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes."

So I have been looking into adding the right scopes for my python project.

I did this for GAM and I thought I would do it in this screen:

Manage API client access (thats in the admin panel).

So I have created a project, enabled the google classroom API, created an  OAuth 2.0 client ID and copied this along with the following scopes:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters,
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.emails,
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.photos,
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses
```

but still no joy.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I have in fact solved my own puzzle by adding in the scopes into my python file with spaces and it works well!